# Filtering Django models but only the many to many through table

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to list all contact but only the primary address. There is a many to many relationship between Contact and Address with a custom through table that contains additional attributes such as "primary".  Below is the core of the models.

```
class Address(models.mode):
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...    

 class Contact(models.model):
            ...
            address = models.ManyToManyField(Address, through='ContactAddress')
    
     class ContactAddress(models.model):
            contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            address_type = models.ForeignKey(ContactAddressType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Contact.objects.all() return all the contacts.

I loop through them to retrieve contact data:

```
for contact in contact
```

I then loop the addresses in an inner loop:

```
for a in contact.address.all
```

How do i limit the address to just the address with the primary=True on the ContactAddress through table?  I still want all contacts, but only the primary address for each contact.  I was hoping to filter at the top level where i return all the contact but anything i tried limits the contacts that are returned to just those that have a primary address.  I want all contacts but only the primary address for each (or no address if no primary address is set on a contact).

Basically, I want to produce the following SQL with the ORM:

```
select * from contact 
join contact_address on contact.id = contact_address.contact_id 
join address on contact_address.address_id = address.id 
where contact_address.primary = true;
```

I realize I could use raw but as I am new to django, I was hoping to learn how to produce the same results with the ORM.

Comment: Multiple contacts can have the same address?

Comment: Yes, consider a collection of contacts from the same company all having the same office address.  The address is only stored once and can be updated for all contacts if the company relocates.

Comment: ** added to original post ** Basically I want to produce this sql with the ORM

select * from contact 
join contact_address on contact.id = contact_address.contact_id 
join address on contact_address.address_id = address.id 
where contact_address.primary = true;